# Rails has_many :through (with additional attributes) save issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, nested-class

I have the model structure defined below.
I am trying to save the additional attributes of the join table along with a user to a plan.
in the rails console I do the following (for testing). I get a mass assign issue, I have followed many posts on here and all the accepts_nested_attributes_for advice out there to no avail. How do I perform the below?

```
u = User.last
p = Plan.new(:name => 'some name here', :description => 'something here')

p.userPlans.build(:user => u, :is_owner => true) 

# error on the above 'can't mass-assign protected attributes: user'
# would like to do p.userPlans.build for a number of users

p.save
```

Is there a way of saving several users to a plan along with the additional join table attributes then do a singe save? Should I just be doing:

```
u = User.last
p = Plan.new(:name => 'some name here', :description => 'something here')
p.userPlans.build(:user_id => u.id, :is_owner => true) 
p.save
```

So what I would like is a plan, with several users, some of those users will have is_owner = true and some set to false. I thought I would be able to pass a User object directly to the userPlans.build?

Any assistance would be much appreciated. I can't see what I am missing here or is what I am doing acceptable?

```
#user is devise
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
                  :remember_me, :token_authenticatable, 
                  :invited, :confirmed_at, :signed_in_count, 
                  :first_name, :last_name, :userPlans_attributes

  has_many :userPlans
  has_many :plans, :through => :userPlans

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :userPlans, :allow_destroy => true
 .
 .
 .

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :user_id, :userPlans_attributes

  has_many :userPlans
  has_many :users, :through => :userPlans

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :userPlans, :allow_destroy => true

end

class UserPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :decision, :is_owner, :plan_id, :token, :user_id

  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Comment: try changing all of the `userPlans` to `user_plans` - rails is very particular about naming conventions

Comment: You can create each UserPlan by doing `:user => u` but that means you have to add `:user` to your attr_accessible list in your UserPlan model.

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies, I will try the 2 above suggestions and report back.

Comment: I tried changing the userPlans to user_plans and this didn't work but from further reading I know this is how it should be. Adding attr_accessible :user to the :userPlans model worked and I can now do what I intended. I was a bit confused about how this worked here and further reading will help cement my understanding. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.